# How to make sure that onDataChanged has been called? And what to do about it?

Tags: android, wear-os

Let's say that i have an activity on my phone, It's task is to send an integer (that the user entered) to a Service in Wear.

In my Activity on the phone, i do a¨

```
Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(mGoogleApiClient, request);
```

And thats it for my activity. In my Wear Service, i implement this

```
public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {}
```

In my onDataChanged, i save the received values in a sharedpreference, to use that value in my activity when i open it.

My question is, how can i be sure that i have received my value when my user opens the wear activity? Google says that onDataChanged will be called when data has changed, but i try changing the integer a few times, with no luck, service doesnt receive anything.

If i didn't receive anything, can i do anything from my activity to reinvoke/kickstart the process of receiving my Data Items?

Comment: As per Android docs, the provided buffer,DataEventBuffer will be closed **After**  onDataChanged method completes. You can check the status of DataEventBuffer using getStatus() call on DataEventBuffer. Can you show how you are Adding this Listner Service? Becauses, as per Android docs, Activities and other short-lived Android components may use addListener(GoogleApiClient, DataApi.DataListener), addListener(GoogleApiClient, MessageApi.MessageListener) and addListener(GoogleApiClient, NodeApi.NodeListener) to receive events for a limited period of time.

Comment: On my first line of code, i can add an .await() and then check if it has finished and sent to the watch. Which it does. My problem is not that its not working. It's working, but it's very unreliable.

As i am writing this, i am thinking that maybe it's because my service (that implements onDataChanged) is not running?

Or maybe i need to do a Wearable.DataApi.getDataItems() in my activity?

Comment: You can make your service override onPeerConnected and onPeerDisconnected to see if it is being used as expected. If it is, then the problem is likely on the sending side. Before you use putDataItem, are you telling the GAPI client to connect? If not, that's your problem -- putDataItem will not automatically connect for you. If those don't fix it -- please post more of your code.

Comment: When I started with `DataApi` I mistakenly assumed that any data change will cause `onDataChanged`. Notice please that if you update `DataItem` to the **same** value as it already has then `onDataChanged` will **not** be called. Perhaps this comment help you.

Comment: I am sending a 22kb string. Theres 1 byte that changes every time

Answer (score 1):

The reason is -as far as i understand- when onDataChanged called first time, for the other times it requires changing to be called again. It can be even a deleting and creating a new file/stream/request and putting it on to Data Layer or disconnecting and connecting the GoogleApiClient. So that the client will understand the data as a new and changed data everytime.

I use an app that in certain times sends data to phone from watch and i delete and create a new file every time.

Answer (score 0):

after onDataChanged() I am forcing

```
mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

only with these setting the onDataChanged() is working for me.

Comment: do want to elaborate why this worked for you for a better understanding for audiences ?